# Flask wtform DateTimefield rendering issue

Tags: python, flask, wtforms

Getting a weird issue with Flask wtform. I create the DateTimeField in the class form, but when I view the page, it shows as `type="text"`.

```
<input id="date" name="date" type="text" value="">
```

Where as I would prefer it to show as `type="datetime-local"`, which gives a nice input box with a drop down calendar and time search if you dont want to enter by hand.

Also all IntegerField, FloatField, are type text too, where as BooleanField and PasswordField operate as they should.

Maybe I'm missing something here. Is this possible with flask and wtforms? Any guidance is greatly appreciated

Here is my code:

index.html

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <p class="lead">This is the index page  </p>
      {{  form.date() }}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

script.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_bootstrap import Bootstrap
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, DateTimeField,  BooleanField
from wtforms.validators import Required
from data import ACTORS

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'some?bamboozle#string-foobar'
Bootstrap(app)
app.config['BOOTSTRAP_SERVE_LOCAL'] = True

class NameForm(FlaskForm):
    date = DateTimeField('Which date is your favorite?', format='%m/%d/%y', validators=[Required()])

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@app.route('/index.html', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():

    form = NameForm()

    return render_template('index.html', form=form)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: First, to get `type="datetime-local"`, you need to use `date=DateTimeLocalField(...)`

Comment: Try deleting the parentheses: `{{  form.date }}`

Comment: Be aware that Firefox and Safari still haven't implemented a nice `datetime-local` field (though iOS Safari has?).  There are browser-specific limitations to the other date and time input types, too. See [here](https://caniuse.com/#search=input%20date)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The core wtforms DateTimeField provides just a text input.  I think what you want is:

```
from wtforms import StringField, BooleanField
from wtforms.fields.html5 import DateTimeLocalField

class NameForm(FlaskForm):
    date = DateTimeLocalField('Which date is your favorite?', format='%m/%d/%y', validators=[Required()])
```

Comment: Since WTForms >= 3.0.0 this is no longer working, instead, just import from wtforms.fields. Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70200622/5750078