# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'wtforms.fields.html5'

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms, wtforms

I have a flask app that uses wtforms.

I have a file which does:

```
from wtforms.fields.html5 import DateField, EmailField, TelField

# rest of the file
```

I just wanted to rebuild my docker container and now I have this error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'wtforms.fields.html5'
```

I have in my `requirements.txt`:

```
flask
flask-login
flask_sqlalchemy
Flask-Mail
pyodbc
requests
waitress
wtforms
```

I tried to add `flask_WTF` but it did not fix it.

Any idea what's going on? I thought of upgrading wtforms but it seems like I have the newest version:

```
pip install wtforms
Requirement already satisfied: wtforms in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (3.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: MarkupSafe in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from wtforms) (2.0.1)
```

Comment: I just wanted to rebuild my docker container too !

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Downgrading `WTForms==2.3.3` solved the issue for me. Thread referenced [here](https://github.com/FAIRplus/imi-data-catalogue/issues/15).

Answer (score 28):

For WTForms >= 3.0.0, just use `wtforms.fields` to import these classes, as the `html5` module [seems to have been retired in 3.0.0a1](https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/3.0.x/changes/?highlight=html5#version-3-0-0a1). So in your case:

```python
from wtforms.fields import DateField, EmailField, TelField
```

See the WTForms documentation on fields for details (for example for [EmailField](https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/3.0.x/fields/?highlight=emailfield#wtforms.fields.EmailField)).